# Custom Folder Color

Tags: directory, colors

my apologies if this is not the right forum for my query.
I am on Ubuntu 16.04.  I found 'Folder Color' application good enough to change the color of a folder.  I set a custom color. 
I got to know that 'Global Color' is the option to change the color of all the folders/sub folders but there is only few color options available.
Is there any way around so that I can set a CUSTOM color as Global Color? 
Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if that is possible to implement via nautilus.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.  Forgot to mention that I've got nemo integrated.  Will it work?

Comment: Yes you can add a custome color to the color list and then set it as global color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the desired folder you would like to add custom color on it. In here, I added `navy` color code is `#000080` (note that this was not in the default color list).

[image]

Now open a terminal and go to this directory `~/.config/folder-color/custom_icons`

Now run `ls -l` find the appropriate custom `.svg` file .In my case it was `folder_custom_131380.svg` and rename it to `folder_color_navy.svg` using

`mv folder_custom_131380.svg folder_color_navy.svg`

Now copy this `folder_color_navy.svg` file to this directory:

`/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/places`

run this command to reload `sudo gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/hicolor/`

Now you are good to go.

Now you should be able to see that custom color is added to the list and you will be able to set it as global color.This is how, you can add as many color as you want.

[image]

Comment: I am glad that it helps